# Obtener específicamente un registro de una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server

estoy tratando de obtener los registros que solamente tenga como único registro el TIPO 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ya... y el codigo que estás tratando donde está ??

Comment: Según veo la estructura de tu tabla, podrías poner "VALOR" en el where: SELECT * FROM TABLAX WHERE TIPO = 2 AND VALOR='VERDURAS';

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas tener una validación para el tipo buscado y otra para buscar los valores que también existen en otros tipos para omitirlos.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLAX X
WHERE TIPO = 2
AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT *
                FROM TABLAX Y
                WHERE TIPO <> 2
                AND Y.VALOR = X.VALOR);
```

Comment: Gracias , me ayudo.